# App shows a white screen after wrapping my layout with a context provider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

This is my layout:

```js
export const metadata = {
  title: "Web App",
  description: "First Project in Next.js",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <div className="max-w-7xl min-h-screen my-0 mx-auto py-0 px-16 flex flex-col justify-between">
            <Nav />
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is the Session Provider:

```
"use client"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

When I wrapped the content of my body in my layout, my app suddenly flashes only a white screen.

Comment: Hi Caesar, have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `AuthProvider` function does contain a `return` statement. So when you call it, it returns `undefined`, hence the white screen. This should fix the issue:

```
"use client";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;
```